# OTRS ITSM Change State

Tags: perl, otrs, change-management, itil

In OTRS ITSM change management we have changes with different status , and we can change the state of a change either by workorders or manually editing the change .
I want to know is it possible that only change manager can change state from pending approval to approved state by manually editing the change and then the rest of the states can be change by changer builder or this change manager.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this can be done, but not without some development. But you're asking on a developer's forum, so I assume this is no problem.

You should modify the occurrences of `if ( $Self->{Config}->{ChangeState} )` in [AgentITSMChangeEdit.pm](https://github.com/OTRS/ITSMChangeManagement/blob/master/Kernel/Modules/AgentITSMChangeEdit.pm) to add your new conditions - probably you should refactor this a little.